# Apache POI Excel XLSX Streaming XML not correctly reading multiple inline Strings

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've got an XLSX Excel file with a single cell.

[image]

When loaded using POI's `WorkbookFactory`, it's read correctly as a single cell.

When read using POI's `XSSFSheetXMLHandler`, it's read as though it was two separate cells.

Sheet XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:worksheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
   <x:sheetData>
      <x:row>
         <x:c t="inlineStr">
            <x:is>
               <x:r>
               <x:rPr>
                  <x:rFont val="Segoe UI Emoji"/>
               </x:rPr>
                  <x:t xml:space="preserve">&#x1f61c;</x:t>
               </x:r>
               <x:r>
                  <x:t xml:space="preserve">more text</x:t>
               </x:r>
            </x:is>
         </x:c>
      </x:row>
   </x:sheetData>
   <x:pageSetup paperSize="9" orientation="portrait" />
</x:worksheet>
```

Normally you'd expect to see a single item of text per cell, but here it's in two blocks - one formatted using a different font to the other.

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageAccess;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.ReadOnlySharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFComment;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class MultiTagTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final File file = new File("Minimised.xlsx");

    try (OPCPackage xlsxPackage = OPCPackage.open(file, PackageAccess.READ)) {
        final XSSFReader reader = new XSSFReader(xlsxPackage);

        final Iterator<InputStream> iter = reader.getSheetsData();

        try (InputStream stream = iter.next()) {
        final SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        saxParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        final XMLReader sheetParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

        sheetParser.setContentHandler(new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(reader.getStylesTable(),
            new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(xlsxPackage), new SheetContentsHandler() {
                @Override
                public void startRow(final int rowNum) {
                }

                @Override
                public void endRow(final int rowNum) {
                }

                @Override
                public void cell(final String cellReference, final String formattedValue,
                    final XSSFComment comment) {
                System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(
                    "XSSFSheetXMLHandler Cell - cellReference={0}, formattedValue={1}, comment={2}",
                    cellReference, formattedValue, comment));
                }
            }, true));

        sheetParser.parse(new InputSource(stream));
        }
    }

    try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file, null, true)) {
        final Row row = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0);

        for (int col = row.getFirstCellNum(); col < row.getLastCellNum(); col++) {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("WorkbookFactory Cell - {0}", row.getCell(col)));
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
XSSFSheetXMLHandler Cell - cellReference=null, formattedValue=, comment=null
XSSFSheetXMLHandler Cell - cellReference=null, formattedValue=more text, comment=null
WorkbookFactory Cell - more text
```

From inside the `SheetContentsHandler`'s `cell` method, it's not possible to tell that they were the same cell.

Comment: Check the Cell Reference?

Comment: @Gagravarr if you look at the output, the cell reference is null.

Comment: Have you tried using Baby Yoda Time?

Comment: You ought to be getting all the text of the cell concatenated together as the argument to the cell method, so it looks like a bug. Assuming you have this issue with the latest stable version, can you open a bug in the Apache POI bugzilla with this code + upload the sample file?

Comment: @Gagravarr raised - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65096

Comment: Looks like PJ Fanning has potentially fixed it for you already!